# how to insert data into array object in c#

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I'm working with Json As i converted that json into classes and my class structure is like below

```
Class Demo
{
    public A a { get; set; }
    public B b { get; set; }
    public C[] c { get; set; }
}

class A
{
public string x{ get; set; }
}
class B
{
public string y{ get; set; }
}
class C
{
public string z{ get; set; }
public D d{ get; set; }
}
class D
{
public string p{ get; set; }

}
```

to assign values to the parameter i'm using below code.

```
 Demo demo = new Demo {

                        a = new A{
                            x = "test data",

                        },
                        b = new B{
                            y = "test data",

                        }
```

for the same class A and B i'm able to assign value but Class C is an array how can i assign parameter value to the class C

Comment: `c = new C[0]` ?

Comment: c = new C[] { new C { z = "1"}, new C { z = "2"}}

Comment: You can work with a list and use LINQ's `ToArray()` particularly if you're going to be reading those from a file/service or user input and cannot hard code it. `c = yourListOfC.ToArray()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate array directly through object initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085930/populate-array-directly-through-object-initializer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways,

```
 Demo demo = new Demo
        {
            a = new A
            {
                x = "test data",
            },
            b = new B
            {
                y = "test data",
            },
            c = new C[]
            {
                new C
                {
                    z = "hello",
                    d = new D
                    {
                        p = "This is D's property"
                    }
                },
                new C
                {
                    z = "Hi",
                    d = new D
                    {
                        p = "Another D's property"
                    }

                },

            }
        };
```

Or add to list and convert to the array. I would recommend the first one.

```
 Demo demo = new Demo
        {
            a = new A
            {
                x = "test data",
            },
            b = new B
            {
                y = "test data",
            },
            c = new List<C>
            {
                new C
                {
                    z = "hello"
                }
            }.ToArray()
        };
```

Here is the full sample program,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Demo demo = new Demo
        {
            a = new A
            {
                x = "test data",
            },
            b = new B
            {
                y = "test data",
            },
            c = new C[]
           {
                new C
                {
                    z = "hello",
                    d = new D
                    {
                        p = "This is D's property"
                    }
                },
                new C
                {
                    z = "Hi",
                    d = new D
                    {
                        p = "Another D's property"
                    }

                },

           }
        };


        Console.WriteLine(demo.a.x);
        Console.WriteLine(demo.b.y);

        foreach (var c in demo.c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.z);
            Console.WriteLine(c.d.p);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Demo
{
    public A a { get; set; }
    public B b { get; set; }
    public C[] c { get; set; }

    public D d { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
    public string x { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string y { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string z { get; set; }
    public D d { get; set; }
}

public class D
{
    public string p { get; set; }

}
```

and the output,

[image]

Comment: What's the point of creating a `List<C>` just to call `ToArray()` on it?

Comment: Well, that was one of the different ways. I have updated the answer with direct to array

Comment: thanks @VijayanathViswanathan it was useful i have one more doubt for that i updated my code in question how can i read data of D class here.

Comment: You want to create Demo object by including D isn't it?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the full sample program. Please have a look and let me know. If not working will chat further.

Answer (score 0):

Create new empty array where each item would be of type `C`:

```
c = new C[0]
```

Create new array with two new items of type `C`, where each item has property values set:

```
c = new C[] { new C { z = "1"}, new C { z = "2"}}
```

However, if you don't know the number of items beforehand, you may be better of using generic enumerables, such as:

```
// Create new empty list
var myList = new List<C>();

// Add a new object to the list
myList.Add(new C());
```